# Relate cheet sheet with event/observer?

Tags: magento

1. Explain the relation between Magento Event/Observer Hooks Cheat Sheet?
2. List item ?

   Example:  is for "Submit invoice". (Sales/ order / new invoice).

   1. I have to relate observer or automated the payment process. Once successful payment is done (by any online payment method). i have to take order id+ customer id & put that in my custom table  named JOB.

Note: i felt observer will be the best option instead of extending class. Suggestion are welcome

Answer (score 0):

after googling through this i came to conclusion that we have to execute `grep -R dispatchEvent`, this can be app or local or any other folder or all.

Comment: Also consider installing the wonderful [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), it's more suited to programmers than grep.